# gke autopilot cluster gke_stockout error on creating cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

trying to start a GKE autopilot cluster in the cloud console. upon creating the cluster in us-central-1 and waiting quite a while, the cluster fails to create with this error message.

```
(1) Google Compute Engine: Not all instances running in IGM after 35m10.304899767s. Expected 1, running 0, transitioning 1. Current errors: [GCE_STOCKOUT]: Instance 'gk3-autopilot-cluster-2-default-pool-e6e58b56-gb1c' creation failed: The zone 'projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-f' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later 
(2) Google Compute Engine: Not all instances running in IGM after 35m8.607215156s. Expected 1, running 0, transitioning 1. Current errors: [GCE_STOCKOUT]: Instance 'gk3-autopilot-cluster-2-default-pool-36625fbc-dsmq' creation failed: The zone 'projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.
```

I tried to create this in different zones, but get the same error so my suspicion is that its not a temporary issue and my configuration is wrong. I tried giving the compute engine default service account more permission for compute resources and kubenetes engine agent permissions but nothing changed.

Comment: Upon my research for GCE_STOCKOUT, Google Cloud resources you need are not currently available.

Most of the recommended is to deploy and balance your workload across multiple zones and regions to reduce the likelihood of an outage and have access to multiple resource pools when you need to expand quickly.

Try this suggestion if this works.

Comment: So you did try other regions such as us-east-*?  We'll look into this, but this is pretty unusual for Autopilot clusters.

Comment: i tried it in us-east1 and us-west1, eventually i tried it again 2 days later and it worked in us-west1. i tried creating autopilot clusters as well as standard clusters.